# How Do You Programmatically Set the Hardware Clock on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, time, clock, hwclock

Linux provides the stime(2) call to set the system time.  However, while this will update the system's time, it does not set the BIOS hardware clock to match the new system time.

Linux systems typically sync the hardware clock with the system time at shutdown and at periodic intervals.  However, if the machine gets power-cycled before one of these automatic syncs, the time will be incorrect when the machine restarts.

How do you ensure that the hardware clock gets updated when you set the system time?

Comment: Specify a programming language.

Comment: Why would the programming language matter?  Do you have different answers for different languages/

Comment: Er................. yes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the rtc man-page for details, but if you are logged in as root, something like this:

```
#include <linux/rtc.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


    struct       rtc_time {
        int         tm_sec;      
        int         tm_min;      
        int         tm_hour;     
        int         tm_mday;     
        int         tm_mon;      
        int         tm_year;     
        int         tm_wday; /* unused */
        int         tm_yday; /* unused */
        int         tm_isdst;/* unused */
    };

int fd;
struct rtc_time rt;
/* set your values here */
fd = open("/dev/rtc", O_RDONLY);
ioctl(fd, RTC_SET_TIME, &rt);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Root not needed, only CAP_SYS_TIME capability according to rtc(4).

Comment: Hello, i have 3 questions regarding trhe answer. 1. Why the own rtc_time and not the one from rtc.h 2. O_RDONLY ? is that not only for read? 3. if i try the code I get from ioctl -1 and errno 22. What does that mean?

Comment: @Offler This answer was not meant as a copy and paste ready to use solution. I included the struct to show how it worked. For a real example view the source code to the `hwclock` program.

Answer (score 8):

After calling stime(), do this:

```
system("/sbin/hwclock --systohc");
```

See the hwclock(8) man page for more information.

Comment: Note that if your rtc is setup to use UTC time you need to add `--utc` or `--localtime` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to point out the hardware clock is only accurate to a point (I have seen systems that will loose/gain a couple of seconds a day).

Have you considered setting up the network time daemon to sync your clock against a time server?

Admittedly this syncing does not happen until after the daemon starts so keeping your hardware clock in sync also helps between the power up and the point the time daemon syncs against the time server.

Comment: Most of those variations, from my experience, are due to low voltage on the motheboard battery. I would suggest checking it before setting up an innecesary service if its not mission critical.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reading the source code of hwclock.

Comment: You might be writing for an embedded system and don't have room for another program.  Or maybe you just want to know for curiosity's sake.

Comment: That was an answer to the original question. I don't know why it is needed.

Comment: @iny, I meant "Why read the source to hwclock, when you could simply call hwclock?"  Zan had a good answer to that.

Comment: Running "strace hwclock" is probably the fastest way to satisfy one's curiosity.

Answer (score -2):

If the text editor is different than kubuntu (kate is the default in editor), use your own with the `sudo` command in terminal.

1. run terminal
2. copy and paste this command
   `sudo kate /etc/default/rcS` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. enter user password (your login password) press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. text editor will open on the desktop
5. change the line `UTC=yes` to `UTC=no`
6. and click save (at top of text editor tab bar)
7. reboot

Comment: Appears to bear no relation to the question asked.