# How to set Linux/Mac computer clock with C#/Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, macos, mono, clock

how can I programmatically set the hardware computer clock under Linux and Mac in C# with the Mono CLR?

## EDIT:

I created a C# library to do this, so if everyone else need this function, grab it here:

https://github.com/mc-kay/sharp-timetools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use PInvoke (documentation : http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) the native (c/c++) functions for this. For linux the native function / struct is listed here : [How Do You Programmatically Set the Hardware Clock on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202116/how-do-you-programmatically-set-the-hardware-clock-on-linux)

Comment: How can I find out which .so file I need to invoke (like the "fd" and "ioctl" function)?

Comment: its not fd its "open" and is present in libc.so :) Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326636/identifying-which-linux-system-library-contains-a-function for finding out ioctl. All the best. Kindly mark as answered if done.