# Set hardware clock on linux not working

Tags: linux, gcc, codeblocks, clock

when i try to set the computer hardware clock like here descripted:

[How Do You Programmatically Set the Hardware Clock on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202116/how-do-you-programmatically-set-the-hardware-clock-on-linux)

its not working (the time is not updated to the new time).

```
fd = open("/dev/rtc", O_RDONLY); //<- return 3

ioctl(fd, RTC_SET_TIME, &rt); //<- return 0
```

When I add

```
system("/sbin/hwclock --systohc");
```

I get:

> Cannot access the Hardware Clock via
>   any known method

Executing hwclock --systohc from the terminal working.

It's a Ubuntu 10.10 mashine in VirtualBox.

I using Code::Blocks 10.05 with GCC 4.4.5

Here is my full source code:

http://pastebin.com/sgBBv1XA

And yes, I execute the programm as root.

Comment: Since you set time to rtc, not set by `stime`. `/sbin/hwclock --hctosys` should be called instead of `--systohc`. `--hctosys` would sync system time from hardware clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt, if it is possible to set HD clock in a machine running in virtual environemnt.

Comment: Does VirtualBox not emulating a virtual RTC?

Comment: @mc-kay You may need to specify UTC to the VM through VirtualBox's options.

Comment: I enabled "Hardware clock in UTC" in the VirtualBox settings.

Comment: I dont have a real Linux machine, so could someone test this code?

Comment: @mc-kay are u able to execute /sbin/hwclock --systohc directly in your shell ?

Comment: I just testet the code on a real linux machine and it's not working too. I get the same retun codes and error message while using system("/sbin/hwclock --systohc"); Using hwclock in the terminal works.

Comment: Whaa...I'am sooo stupid ^^ Setting the RTC works in a real machine, only the Gnome clock is not updating the new time. hwclock shows the correct time ;-)